# How to check Databricks cluster for Log4J vulnerability?

Tags: azure, log4j, databricks

I'm using a Databricks cluster version 7.3 LTS with Scala 2.12. This version does use Log4J.

The [official docs](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/7.3.html) say that it uses Log4J version `1.2.17`. Does this mean I do not have this vulnerability? And if I do, can I manually patch it on the cluster or do I need to upgrade the cluster to the next LTS version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log4j 1: How to mitigate the vulnerability in log4j without updating version to 2.15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332054/log4j-1-how-to-mitigate-the-vulnerability-in-log4j-without-updating-version-to)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you wrote most Databricks clusters use 1.2.17 so it is different version and version affected by vulnerability is not used by Databricks.

Only one problem is  when you install different version by yourself on the cluster. Even when you installed affected version you can mitigate the problem by setting Spark config in cluster advanced config as below:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions "-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions "-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"
```

Comment: isn't that configuration only available in log4j 2.10+?

Comment: it is for people who manually installed log4j 2 on clusters

Comment: There is also official message from databricks regarding CVE-2021-44228 https://databricks.com/blog/2021/12/13/log4j2-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228-research-and-assessment.html it is exactly as answer but much more detailed

Answer (score 1):

you get complete e2e update on this here : https://databricks.com/blog/2021/12/13/log4j2-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228-research-and-assessment.html